# Create File shortcut with Symfony2 FileSystem

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

Anyone know how to use the Filesystem component Symfony2 to create shortcut files? Or another way to create a file shortcut?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.symlink.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$filesystem = new Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$filesystem->symlink($originDir, $targetDir, $copyOnWindows = false);
```

Reason to use Symfony Filesystem over the native PHP `symlink` would be because this method will prepare the directory for you, converts triggered errors into exceptions, and manages compatibility on Windows which doesn't support symlinks, so creates a copy instead.

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L289

Comment: Actually this may not work with individual files, only directories that contain the files

Comment: Failed to create Symlink when i try it